# bert-case from portugese to english

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, squad

I'm trying to build bert question-answering model.
This is from where I'm trying to build it:
https://nbviewer.org/github/piegu/language-models/blob/master/question_answering_BERT_large_cased_squad_v11_pt.ipynb

```
model_name_or_path = "neuralmind/bert-large-portuguese-cased"
dataset_name = "squad11pt"
```

The above is the path for portugese. I want to change it to English. I have tried using path name as

```
bert-large-cased
```

but it's not working. Can someone tell me how I can change the dataset to English?

Comment: What do you mean it isn't working? Also do you want to change the model weights or the dataset?

Comment: I wanted a squad dataset which is in English so I was wondering what should be the path and dataset name given instead of portugese?